# How to prevent a port number to other sub domains using Nginx v1.14.1?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

Have two Sub Domains, app.example.com and admin.example.com, using nginx v 1.14.1, express js.

Bugs:

1. The ports are running in both subdomains eg: 8080 runs in app.example.com and admin.example.com how can I prevent this?
2. It's not redirecting to 80 after entering subdomains with port number 8080 and 8081. or I should prevent entering this port number from URL.

**virtual.conf**

```
server {
      listen admin.example.com:80;
      server_name admin.example.com;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      }
}

server {
      listen app.example.com:80;
      server_name app.example.com;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
      }
}
```

Comment: firewall, or inside your node project `app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1')`

Comment: @RolandStarke - I have done it, now showing Nginx welcome page, telling us to edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, what is next?

Comment: Only for `app.example.com` and `admin.example.com` shows  this welcome screen

Comment: And before changing the `app.listen` it worked? Sry can't help. (i would go for `listen 80;`)

Comment: Yes, early it's pointing to my projects. now showing welcome screen. I think now we need another setup using `nginx.conf`

Comment: @RolandStarke - We are solved the Bugs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

- Changed server.js line `app.listen('8080')` to `app.listen('8080', '127.0.0.1')`
- Restarted the nginx then got nginx welcome page for all my subdomains and private IP.
- Removed subdomain name from virtual.conf at the line of `listen`.
- Restared `nginx` again.

**virtual.conf**

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name admin.example.com;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      }
}

server {
      listen 80;
      server_name app.example.com;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
      }
}
```